# Windows 10 wireless connection won't connect after using Linux Mint 20

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, linux-mint

I had Windows 10 but I wanted to try Linux Mint 20 so I installed it "alongside windows 10".

Now, my problem is that I can't connect to my WiFi on Windows 10 after using Linux Mint. I necessarily have to unplug and plug the my USB WiFi device (TP Link TL-WN727N).

That's only after previously using Mint, otherwise everything works great. That means, if I reboot or shutdown the PC but I keep using only windows 10, I will not have this problem

When I go to the WiFi adapter, it shows "attempting to reconnect". I've used the troubleshooting guide from windows with no success.

Edit: forgot to clarify that WiFi works on Linux Mint at all times and all the drivers are up to date

Comment: It would appear the Mint Wireless driver is changing key settings that a restart fixes. Try updating the Mint driver. Also consider making Mint a Virtual Machine to prevent this issue.

Comment: So does it work under Mint?

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Drivers are up to date in both OS. WiFi works under Mint at all times.

Comment: When back in Windows, try running TCP/IP Reset:  Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
Then: netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
Then: ipconfig /flushdns     See if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if you have configured the adaptor differently in each of the two boot environments. For example, DHCP under Windows, but fixed IP under Linux.

What will happen then is that after you've been running Linux, you boot to Windows but meanwhile the USB device  has remained powered on. This can happen even if your reboot was a power-off, since computers can continue to supply power to USB when the computer is switched off.

Since the USB device has remained powered on, it is able to retain information about its operational state under Linux, which may include the (non-) DHCP mode and IP address provided under Linux.

To use the adaptor successfully under both boot environments, you should ensure you have configured it the same in both environments (either for DHCP, using the same DHCP server, or for the same fixed IP address and subnet mask).